No data about Loading Time on Google Console
We uploaded our Android app to play store. But there is no data regarding Loading time. What could be the reason?
We are trying the Macrobenchmark right now. But it is too problematic on a multi module project. So we would like to get data on startup time via play console.
I checked the Loading time section on console to check if there is any action requiered but there is nothing.

Try integrating Firebase performance https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon. As far as I know, data on Playstore has slow interval updates
